Crossover Equivalence - Does AB/ab X AB/ab result in no effect in crossover 50% of the time when crossover occurs?
I might be using symbols wrong, so my symbol definitions for this post:

DEFINITIONS:
AB / ab : gene alignment on chromatids.

Another way of looking at the above is
a   b
----- chromatid 1
----- chromatid 2
A   B

or
a||A
b||B


AB/ab || ab/AB : alignment of sister chromosomes during metaphase I when alignment occurs. So in this case, crossing over of ab and ab would result in no effect on the gametes
AB/ab X AB/ab: Crossing two parents

If you were crossing AB/ab X AB/ab with a mu of 20 between a and b, that would imply crossing over occurs 20% of the time. When crossing over, the chromosomes could be aligned either:
AB/ab || ab/AB, 
AB/ab || AB/ab, 
ab/AB || ab/AB, 
ab/AB || AB/ab. 
This implies to me that 50% of the time during crossing over events with AB/ab, there would be no effect of the cross-over for the genes a and b.
This would then imply to me that the gamete distribution would be:
AB: 45% (40% from no crossover, 5% from crossover)
ab: 45% (same reasoning)
Ab: 5%
aB: 5%
Which if you then did the test cross, would mean if you were asked what is the frequency of AB/AB in the cross progeny, that the resulting progeny would be 45%*45% = 20.25% AB/AB, and not 16% AB/AB if crossing over always resulted in unique gametes.
Is the above reasoning correct?

I also don't see any reference to this either, what I assume to either be a misattribution or misunderstanding of how the process works, or that it's already baked into the understanding of MU and that crossing over would always result in effective cross-over and not just a 'null' cross-over

I am thinking that mu already bakes this assumption of recombination of two genes by definition, as recombination is looked at wrt two genes.
